# To which linux device an EC2 volume is liked?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running 'Amazon EC2 Linux'.

It has 5 volumes attached to it. All has an 'in-use' State and an 'Okay' Status.

[image]

I didn't configure the instance and I would like to find out to which linux device every EC2 volume is 
attached ?

I suspect that some of the volumes are not connected to the EC2 instance because I have access to only about a half of the volumes' total space.

I ran 'df -h' on shell and got the results:

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1              7.9G  1.4G  6.5G  18% /
tmpfs                   3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vg0-data    195G   45G  141G  24% /data
/dev/mapper/vg0-log     11G  689M  9.6G   7% /log
/dev/mapper/vg0-journal 11G  156M   11G   2% /journal
```

Than  I ran 'lsblk' on the shell and got the results:

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN     RM  SIZE    RO TYPE     MOUNTPOINT

xvda1               202:1       0   8G      0   disk    /

xvdh4               202:116     0   110G    0   disk
md127               9:127       0   219.9G  0   raid10
vg0-data (dm-0)     253:0       0   197.9G  0   lvm     /data
vg0-log (dm-1)      253:1       0   11G     0   lvm     /log
vg0-journal (dm-2)  253:2       0   11G     0   lvm     /journal

xvdh3               202:115     0   110G    0   disk
md127               9:127       0   219.9G  0   raid10
vg0-data (dm-0)     253:0       0   197.9G  0   lvm     /data
vg0-log (dm-1)      253:1       0   11G     0   lvm     /log
vg0-journal (dm-2)  253:2       0   11G     0   lvm     /journal

xvdh2               202:114     0   110G    0   disk
md127               9:127       0   219.9G  0   raid10
vg0-data (dm-0)     253:0       0   197.9G  0   lvm     /data
vg0-log (dm-1)      253:1       0   11G     0   lvm     /log
vg0-journal (dm-2)  253:2       0   11G     0   lvm     /journal

xvdh1               202:113     0   110G    0   disk
md127               9:127       0   219.9G  0   raid10
vg0-data (dm-0)     253:0       0   197.9G  0   lvm     /data
vg0-log (dm-1)      253:1       0   11G     0   lvm     /log
vg0-journal (dm-2)  253:2       0   11G     0   lvm     /journal
```

Im new to Amazon EC2 and Im not an expert on Linux system.

I guess that what I need is an explanation of these result.

Thanx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On EC2 console All of them have status 'is-use'.

While you are at it, you just need to read the "Entire Row" carefully. Look for the "Attachment Information" column. It will show which instance the volume is attached and the device name:

[image]

If you see the last column of the screen shot above, you would see that it is attached as `/dev/sda1`. and just before that it would list the instance id/name which I have erased from the screen shot.

***UPDATE:***
posting update after OP changed the entire questions.

`xvdh1, xvdh2, xvdh3 and xvdh4` are part of **"Device Mapper"** (`dm-0, dm-1 and dm-2`) which is used by **LVM**. There are 3 Logical Volumes (LVM) created viz: `/dev/mapper/vg0-data, /dev/mapper/vg0-log and /dev/mapper/vg0-journal`. These 3 logical volumes are mounted on `/data, /log and journal` respectively.

run `dmsetup ls` to see more information around "dm-*" devices.

Comment: thanks.I do know the devices names. I'll edit my question to share more info.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon console go to ec2 and select volume and you will see the attached information which instance id using this volume and also login ec2 instance and check "lsblk" you will see the attached device name and also you can check using file -s dev/xdef* whether this device are being used or not.